# Entity authentication using .Net HttpWebRequest and NetworkCredential

Tags: c#, .net, security

I am looking at the results from IBM's AppScan and it is saying that I have a Vulnerability.Authentication.Entity issue when I use the NetworkCredential class to store my username and password for an instance of the HttpWebRequest class.

I am a novice on this specific security issue so I have been researching for the last couple of days but I am not sure if I have an issue or is Appscan just wrong on this. (see code snipet below).  Appscan is not liking when I create the NetworkCredential object

```
    var request = WebRequest.Create(uri);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
    {
     request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
    }

    var httpRequest = request as HttpWebRequest;
    if (httpRequest != null)
    {
     httpRequest.UserAgent = SyndicationDiscoveryUtility.FrameworkUserAgent;
    }
    return request;
```

Comment: Does AppScan give you and details of why the validation error is thrown? What type of authentication is the web server expecting? Basic? NTLM? etc?

Comment: AppScan does not give a why.  The server side is unknown.  The functionality of the class the code is in allows the user to configure a process to go out and hit a service and return the data.  So there are a lot of unknowns